# call synchrounously process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am stuck in nodejs during calling of zendesk api.

As i called zendesk.tickets.incremental Api, it provides me ticketId and that used in another function for getting any change from previous by calling zendesk.tickets.exportAudit.

I also get response too but during fetching the data another ticketId called so previously flag an error in response "error: item not found " and than fetch the data for new ticketId and so on.

What I need, I need it block the process until data of first Id completely .

This is my code.

```
//Calling ticketIncremental Details ticketId (likes 1, 2 etc)
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {        

     zendesk.tickets.incremental(0, function(err, statusList, body, responseList, resultList) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } 

        var ticketIncreDetails = (JSON.stringify(body));

        res.end(ticketIncreDetails);

       for (var i=0; i< body.length; i++ ) {

        ticketValues(body[i].id) //within this function another API of zendek calling for exportAudit

       }

 });


//This is for exportAudit

    function ticketValues(ticketId) {

        zendesk.tickets.exportAudit(ticketId, function(err,statusList, body, responseList, resultList) {

            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

         console.log("ticketExportAudit: " + JSON.stringify(body))      });
```

Comment: There is pretty much always another solution, but you could check out the [`sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync) package. Other than that, your question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As @qxz say, it's better to check out if there is sync package or not, or you need to handle this focusing on callback because **zendesk.tickets.exportAudit** need time to complete its work, but for loop wouldn't act like that, the code below handle this problem with callback, you could have a look.

```
 //Calling ticketIncremental Details ticketId (likes 1, 2 etc)
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {        

     zendesk.tickets.incremental(0, function(err, statusList, body, responseList, resultList) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } 

        var ticketIncreDetails = (JSON.stringify(body));

        res.end(ticketIncreDetails);


        ticketValues(body,body.length,0); 
        //ticketValues(body,body.length,0,function(){..if you wanna do something after..}); 


     });

 });
    //This is for exportAudit

    function ticketValues(ticket,length,index,callback) {

        zendesk.tickets.exportAudit(ticke[index].id, function(err,statusList, body, responseList, resultList) {
          if(index<length){
              if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
              }else{
                console.log("ticketExportAudit: " + JSON.stringify(body));
                index++;
                ticketValues(ticket,length,index,callback);
              }

          }else{

             if(callback)
                callback();
          }

       });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response and happy at least it wait.

I tried your solution and its working up-to 3-4 tickets and after-word i got this error

{ [Error: Zendesk Error (404): Item not found] statusCode: 404, result: , retryAfter: null }

While zendesk may contain no.of tickets, at present having 12 tickets.

Would you like to share me how can handle this up-to Nth no.of tickets?

Comment: @vicky Not really understand your problem , but if you want to skip them,because of your code handling err with 
  **if(err) { console.log(err);return;}**
, just replace them like

**if(err) {console.log(err);index++;ticketValues(ticket,length,index,callback);}** 
and they'll be skipped .

Comment: Thanks Carr your idea is working but I use another way, I choose async.series.

Comment: OK ~ that should be a more elegant way =)